# Convert a string IP column to integer in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with IPv4 values as strings, and I want to convert them into their integer values. Preferably without a UDF that might have a large performance impact.

Example input:

```
+---------------+
|         IP_str|
+---------------+
|      4.8.1.235|
|    50.17.11.18|
|   48.104.99.80|
+---------------+
```

Example output:

```
+---------------+
|         IP_int|
+---------------+
|       67633643|
|      839977746|
|      812147536|
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **`multiply`** with `number of addresses` per network(i.e. **`16777216,65536,256,1`**).

- Split **`ip_address`** with `.` and multiply with number of addresses.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+------------+
#|      IP_str|
#+------------+
#|   4.8.1.235|
#| 50.17.11.18|
#|48.104.99.80|
#+------------+
df.withColumn("IP_int",split(col("IP_str"),"\.")[0]*16777216 +split(col("IP_str"),"\.")[1]*65536+ split(col("IP_str"),"\.")[2]*256 + split(col("IP_str"),"\.")[3]).\
show()
#+------------+---------+
#|      IP_str|   IP_int|
#+------------+---------+
#|   4.8.1.235| 67633643|
#| 50.17.11.18|839977746|
#|48.104.99.80|812147536|
#+------------+---------+
```